# Using Generics to Access Classes in an XNA Game

Tags: c#, generics, reference, xna

If I have a class that is based off another class, how do I access the properties of the first class if it can have any name? I was thinking of using generics to access the properties, but the generics are "generic" for a reason...

For example:

```
public class AGameInXNA : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
     int ExampleGameProperty;
}

// ... another class ... //

public class ReferenceToAGameInXNA
{
     Game gameInstance;
     public void SetGameInstance(Game game)
     {
          gameInstance = game;
     }

     public void SetExampleGameProperty()
     {
          gameInstance.ExampleGameProperty = 21; // I don't know the name of
                                                 // AGameInXNA, so I want to
                                                 // access it using a generic
                                                 // class.
     }
}
```

I know that that does not work, so how would I use generics in this case to access the `AGameInXNA`'s properties in another class if I don't know `AGameInXNA`'s name?

EDIT: I am trying to make it so that I can reuse this code later on. I want to be able to have a class that is unknown, such as `public class unknownclassname` that extends another class, such as `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game`, and be able to access the class `unknownclassname` without directly calling/implementing it in the library code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking into [XNA Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.services.aspx).

So for example, you would create a service which could be as simple as an

```
interface IExamplePropertyService
{
  int ExampleProperty { get; set; }
}

public class AGameInXNA : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game, IExamplePropertyService
{ 
     int ExampleGameProperty { get; set; }

     void Initialize()
     {
         // Do other initialization
         Services.Add( typeof(IExamplePropertyService), this );
     }
} 

public class ReferenceToAGameInXNA    
{    
     IExamplePropertyService propertyService;    
     public void GetGameInstance(Game game)    
     {    
          propertyService = (IExamplePropertyService)game.GetService( typeof(IExamplePropertyService) );    
     }    

     public void SetExampleGameProperty()    
     {    
          propertyService.ExampleGameProperty = 21;  
     }    
}
```

Implement it, and register it with the Game component, then in your ReferenceToAGameInXNA, you would query for this service and store it (rather than the Game) for use later.

As a bonus benefit, The IExamplePropertyService no longer even needs to be implemented by the Game class, it could be implemented by any GameComponent.

This makes for an easy way to seperate classes from having to know about the inner workings of other classes in the Game.  So long as the services exist somewhere, your ReferenceToAGameInXNA can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think generics are what you are actually looking for here.  In your second class, just change the type of all of the `gameInstance` to the type of the class you created for your game, in this case `AGameInXNA`.  There should only be a need for one subclass of the Game type in each XNA game.  That will allow you to access any public members of `AGameInXNA` from the Reference class.

If this isn't what you are after, please give a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to accomplish and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know XNA, but if you want to have several classes that inherit from `Game` and have the same property on all of them, you could create an abstract class that inherits from `Game` and let the other classes inherit from that instead.

(Also, your `GetGameInstance()` is badly named, because it *sets* the field, it doesn't get it. And it's probably better as property anyway.)

```
public abstract class GameBase : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
     public int ExampleGameProperty { get; set; }
}

public class AGameInXNA : GameBase
{
    // code specific to AGameInXNA 
}

public class ReferenceToAGameInXNA
{
     public GameBase GameInstance { get; set; }

     public void SetExampleGameProperty()
     {
          GameInstance.ExampleGameProperty = 21;
     }
}
```

If the other classed that have `ExampleGameProperty` shouldn't inherit from `Game`, you could create an interface instead. `AGameInXNA` would then inherit from `Game` directly and it would also implement the interface. And you would work with that interface in `ReferenceToAGameInXNA`.

Comment: If I have a few properties that are defined ONLY in `AGameInXNA`, how would I access those specific properties?

Comment: Then you know that it's `AGameInXNA` and should you treat it that way. If what you get is `Game`, but you know it's actually `AGameInXNA`, you can use casting.

Answer (score 0):

using "Game gameInstance;" you can not acess ExmpleProp. You should use "AGameInXNA gameInstance;" too access ExampleProp.